# Retrieve Last 'N' records from SQLite via ContentProvider

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

I need to retrieve last 25 rows from a table using **`ContentProvider.`** I have searched and came up with a solution which works fine on simple **`SQL Database`**.

`SELECT * FROM`**`( SELECT * FROM [Customers] ORDER BY CustomerID DESC limit 25)`**`ORDER BY CustomerID ASC;`

But as i said , m using **`ContentProvider`**, and in my `onCreateLoader` the procedure is like this :

`CursorLoader(getActivity(), uri, projection, selection, null, sortOrder);`

in which the bold portion of the above query i.e. `FROM` can only be a `Uri`.

And if i use 
    `( SELECT * FROM [Customers] ORDER BY CustomerID DESC limit 25)` as a `Uri` then Exception says that is not a valid Uri.

Is there any other way to achieve my objective or any modification in this query. Thanx.

Comment: Other way would be using a List. Put everything in List and just take last N records from the List

Comment: But i think that would be a memory killing way...

Answer (score 0):

Tell the content provider to return rows sorted by `CustomerID DESC`.
Once you have that cursor, just take the first 25 rows out of it, and sort them again, manually. (In this case, just reverse the order of the rows.)

If you still need to have the data in a cursor afterwards, store the values in your own [MatrixCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html).

Comment: I think the solution that i mentioned in my question is the same one that u r giving. But thnx , i solved my problems using alot of string appending .